# How to parse a date-time string with extra characters like (+0) in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am parsing log files which contain a timestamp with some extra text at the end.

```
2023-02-10 08:16:15.123456(+0)
```

I am not sure what the (+0) means, but the values change randomly. (+12), (+123), (+1234) are all possible values.

I can get the entire string except the what is in parenthesis. I noticed if I add `(+0)` to the format it works, but only for exactly `(+0)`

```
Import datetieme.
datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-02-10 08:16:15.123456(+125)','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f(+125)')
Out[176]: datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 10, 8, 16, 15, 123456)

datetime.datetime.strptime('2023-02-10 08:16:15.123456(+125)','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f(+0)')
ValueError: time data '2023-02-10 08:16:15.123456(+125)' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f(+0)'
```

Is there a way to handle any value in the parenthesis? Hopefully without having to remove them from all the strings.

Update:
As FObersteiner suggested, I split on "(" and it seems to work. I still don't know the meaning of the extra filed so I am ignoring it for now.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(orderDF.iloc[0,0].split("(")[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
Out[189]: datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 26, 4, 16, 38, 130088)
```

Comment: afaik there's no way to handle this with built-in strptime methods. If I'd need the value, I'd extract it with a regex. If it's unimportant and the format is otherwise constant, I'd split on `(` and parse the first part with `fromisoformat`.

Comment: Could be nanoseconds? But that is a strange way to format it

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's more likely to be a time zone offset in minutes, but still very non-standard.

Comment: I don't think it is a timezone as it changes too often and not nanoseconds as the values can be large or over 10000. If I can find the reason for it I will post it. Thank you.

Comment: Could be an offset of the system clock vs. some monotonic clock.